# F# - keeping track of state

Tags: f#

I'm building a cache system in F#.  One of the things I want to do is keep track of the total cache hits and cache misses for the duration of the programs runtime.  So, for instance I may have a function like this:

```
member this.Exists key =
            match HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key) with
            | null -> false
            | result -> true
```

Where in the true null case I want to also increment a miss counter, and in the false case I want to also increment a hit counter.  Now I can use a mutable variable and do this no problem, but I'm wondering how one would go about this with a pure functional approach, or more idiomatic F# approach, with the end goal of being able to display the current count of cache hits and misses to user as the program runs.

Comment: the cache itself is highly non-pure so I would not bother with any pure state-monad thingy ... just use mutable variables - cases like this are exactly where you should use those IMO (it's a rather harmless side-effect anyway)

Comment: btw: as you can see you don't use `this` or `result` anywhere - this is why you usually write `member __.Exists key = ...` and `| _ -> true` instead

Comment: An interesting twist would be to expose the type with an [IObservable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx) and track the changes in a separate class.

Comment: Thanks Carsten,  regarding that `__.Exists` tip are there any implications aside from style on that?

Comment: none - indeed `__` is a valid *name* - it's used because it's so similar to the *I don't care* catch-all pattern `_`

Comment: Ohhh, I can put ANYTHING there. heh.  So much to learn.

Comment: @GuyCoder KISS says that's probably not the best idea (you had to deal with blocking/throwing oberserers, etc. when a simple `incr counter`  would do as well

Comment: yes - any name you like - common choices are `this`, `x` and `__` ;) - if you us VisualStudio you can grab yourself the [PowerTools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff) and they will recommend some of those (a bit like Resharper does) for you

Comment: Keep in mind that if you just use mutable variables, such counters will not be thread-safe. This can be fixed either by doing the `IObservable` approach as suggested by @GuyCoder, or simply with `Interlocked.Increment` / `Decrement`.

Answer (score 3):

I would also not worry too much about performance counting being pure. It is a side-effect by definition and so it makes sense to keep some mutable state for it.

For example, you could add `static` (or not `static`) member to your class and just mutate it:

```
type Cache() = 
  static let mutable missCounter = 0
  static let mutable hitCounter = 0
  member this.Exists key =
    match HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key) with
    | null -> missCounter <- missCounter + 1; false
    | result -> hitCounter <- hitCounter + 1; true
```

Comment: I think the keywords HttpRuntime.Cache should ring some bells. This is inherintly concurrent and I'm somewhat concerned about such code as this in general, and especial in HttpRuntime context. Fyodor Soikin also mentions this above.